# How to avoid autoClose in Popup component?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

Is there anyway to avoid autoClose property on Popup component?
I would like something like this, but autoClose prop does not exist in react-leaflet.

```
<Marker position={coords}>
  <Popup autoClose={false}>
    Some text
  </Popup>
</Marker>
```

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, a few [Leaflet Popup options](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html#popup-option) are not exposed via `Popup` component props in `react-leaflet` library.

The following solution could be considered to assign those properties:

Introduce a [callback function](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs) to access Leaflet Popup via `popup.leafletElement`:

```
<Popup ref={popupEl => this.assignPopupProperties(popupEl)}>
        Melbourne
</Popup>
```

and then update *directly* [Leaflet Popup options](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html#popup-option):

```
assignPopupProperties(popup) {
   popup.leafletElement.options.autoClose = false;
   popup.leafletElement.options.closeOnClick = false;
}
```

Here is a [demo](https://4rlx422370.codesandbox.io/#close) and a [source code](https://codesandbox.io/s/4rlx422370)

Answer (score 2):

I found the way to do it. You hove to set both properties autoClose and closePopupOnClick:

```
<Map center={position} zoom="12" closePopupOnClick={false}>
  <Marker position={coords}>
    <Popup autoClose={false}>
      I'm a popup
    </Popup>
  </Marker>
</Map>
```